# "unable to initialize application 0xc000005"

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, sfml

I wrote a wrapper for SFML that would allow me to replace the renderer for my game if I needed to. It worked. Then I refactored and while it still compiles, I now get "unable to initialize application 0xc000005" when running the compiled executable.

What would cause such an error? Google was unhelpful. I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: I think more detail will be needed to provide much beyond the obvious "Something went wrong in refactoring."

Comment: Short of posting all my code, what would you recommend?

Comment: Mostly the obvious -- use your version control system to look at what you changed while refactoring. Either selectively roll back changes until it works again, or roll them all back and then roll forward selectively until it breaks again, to isolate the problem. Once you've isolated the problem, the fix may be obvious, or you may want to post the relevant code asking how that change could break things.

Comment: Are you mixing debug exe/dlls with release exe/dlls or vice versa?  Sometimes there are issues with that.  Try using depends.exe to make sure all dependencies are found.

Comment: So has this question been resolved yet or is it still in need of an answer?

Answer (score 2):

`0xc000005` is `ERROR_ACCESS_VIOLATION` -- you've got a wild pointer somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally gotten this error when I have the following setup:

Application linked against X.lib, which causes a dynamic load of X.dll
X.dll linked against Y.lib, which causes a dynamic load of Y.dll

Run application when X.dll is in the path, but not Y.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you didn't initialize glew and used it somewhere in your code. Try putting `glewInit();` somewhere at start of your code.